# error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. while trying modify firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im tryin to learn about firestore

and here is the dart analysis

> error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

you can see the code here

```
`enter code here` https://pastebin.com/8bSrUfac
```

> "the error cause of "e.data()['name']" at line 33

and this is the itemcard class

```
`enter code here` https://pastebin.com/SfZxBmQJ
```

Anyone can help me find the answer ?
hehe :V

Comment: cant find the line e.data()['name'] in the code you posted...pls post complete code to understand

Comment: om, im so sorry, im just edit the code

Comment: still user.get() function code is missing